# Построение растра силами Яндекса

Tags: csv, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Как сделать лучше - на PHP или на API.Yandex? Есть текстовый файл с тремя столбцами (широта, долгота, значения температуры), надо построить на его основе полноцветное изображение и положить на карту. Часть выкладки на карту не интересует, она уже есть (сделана и работает). А вот как построить растровое изображение по текстовому файлу? есть файл с палитрой дополнительно. Непонятно, как использовать цвет, если построить изображение как набор линий от точки до следующей и затем применить интерполяцию?

Comment: Точки на регулярной решётке?

Comment: Предположим, что да, на регулярной